# hide the label of checkbox - Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I want to know how to hide the label of a check box using hide () in js, now I can hide the check box, but I tried to disable the tag and it does not work.

```
<?= $form->field($modelQuestion, "[{$indexQuestion}]justificar_respuesta")->checkbox(array(
                                            'label'=>'',
                                            'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),
                                            ))->label('You want a response justified ?');?>
```

js

Comment: Hide entire div not just checkbox. Label can be hidden directly by `)->label(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the point of doing so by js, but, this is how you can handle it:

Define `id` attribute for your checkbox:

```
<?= $form->field($modelQuestion, "[{$indexQuestion}]justificar_respuesta")->checkbox(['id' => 'myId', 'labelOptions' => ['style'=>'padding:5px;']])->label('You want a response justified ?');?>
```

And jQuery:

```
$("label[for='myId']").contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.nodeType == 3);
}).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks was just what I was looking for, but now how do I show it again?